# Image field is null ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, asp.net-core

When I add image and try to create a product image field is null. I can't figure out what the problem is, because the file name was visible in the image field.

It's just showing that image field is required, but image is not adding.

What do I need to do to add it properly?

This is how my code looks like - this is my model

```
public class Products
{
    [Key, NotNull, Required]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [Required, NotNull]
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public int Price { set; get; }
    public int Quantity { set; get; }
    public string image { set; get; }
}
```

Product controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create(Products obj, IFormFile? file)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string wwwRootPath = _hostEnvironment.WebRootPath;

        if (file != null)
        {
            string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var upload = Path.Combine(wwwRootPath, @"lib");
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

            using (var fileStreams = new FileStream(Path.Combine(upload, fileName + extension), FileMode.Create))
            {
                file.CopyTo(fileStreams);
            }

            obj.image = @"\lib\" + fileName + extension;
        }

        _db.Products.Add(obj);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        TempData["success"] = "Product created successfully";
        return RedirectToAction("Products");
    }

    return View(obj);   
}
```

Create product view

```
@model Products

<body class="bg-black">
    <div class="container">
        <form method="post" asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="border p-3 mt-4">
                <div class="row pb-2">
                    <h2 class="text-white">Create product</h2>
                </div>
                <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>

                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label asp-for="Name" class="text-white"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label asp-for="Price" class="text-white"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Price" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label asp-for="Quantity" class="text-white"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Quantity" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label asp-for="image" class="text-white"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Quantity" type="file" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn bg-white text-black" style="width:150px">Create</button>
                <a asp-controller="ProductController1" asp-action="Products" class="btn btn-secondary" style="width:150px">
                    Back to list
                </a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

@section Scripts
{
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: your implementation is flawed. Please go through this to understand how to use FormFile type. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?source=recommendations&view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0):

> When I add image and try to create a product image field is null

You need to keep the same  name  with image , refer to the below steps:

1. change

> `<input asp-for="Quantity" type="file" class="form-control" />`

into

```
 <input asp-for="image" type="file" class="form-control" />
```

2. make change to your model like below:

   ```
     public IFormFile image { get; set; }
   ```

3.And in your create action keep the same name too:

```
public IActionResult Create(Products obj, IFormFile? image)
```

**Or** you want to set image by

> obj.image = @"\lib" + fileName + extension;

you need to add  `name="file"` to your code

> `<input asp-for="Quantity" type="file"  name="file" class="form-control" />`